# Angular Material - infinite scroll not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angular Material's infinite scroll, which is defined here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

My first question is: does this virtualRepeat demand to be inside a div with a scrollbar, or can it be applied to the whole page? I actually don't want to have my content inside another div with additional scrollbar (besides the browser's one).

So, I'm using `$http` and my service returns 30 items if I provide a value of 0, and 60 if I provide value of 1, etc.

```
var _page = 0;
$scope.infiniteItems = {
    numLoaded_: 0,
    toLoad_: 0,

    // Required.
    getItemAtIndex: function(index) {
        if (index > this.numLoaded_) {
            this.fetchMoreItems_(index);
            return null;
        }
        return index;
    },

    // Required.
    // For infinite scroll behavior, we always return a slightly higher
    // number than the previously loaded items.
    getLength: function() {
        return this.numLoaded_ + 5;
    },

    fetchMoreItems_: function(index) {

        // For demo purposes, we simulate loading more items with a timed
        // promise. In real code, this function would likely contain an
        // $http request.

        if (this.toLoad_ < index) {
            this.toLoad_ += 30;
            postFactory.getPastPosts(_page).then(angular.bind(this, function(data) {
                this.numLoaded_ = this.toLoad_;
                _page++;
            }));
        }
    }
};
```

Here's my HTML

```
        <md-content flex layout-padding> 

        <div class="virtualRepeatdemoInfiniteScroll">
            <md-list>
                <md-virtual-repeat-container id="vertical-container">
                  <div md-virtual-repeat="post in infiniteItems" md-on-demand="" class="repeated-item" flex="">
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                    {{post}}
                    <past-post model="post" action="reaction(currentPost, candidate, type)"></past-post>
                  </div>
                </md-virtual-repeat-container>                      

                </span>
            </md-list>
        </div>

    </md-content>
```

The problem is that nothing happens. I get no values. The problem is probably in the `postFactory.getPastPosts(_page).then(angular.bind(this, function(data) {` as well, since the data is actually in `data.data`, but there is nothing in the documentation that would show where and how to set the data.

**UPDATE**

The code for `getPastPosts` is pretty straightforward: a basic `$http` request:

```
function getPastPosts(page) {
    return $http.get(baseUrl + '/api/content/past-posts/' + page)
}
```

I'm using this in various part of the application so there's no doubt that it's working.

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint in and checking what's available inside the `then()`?

Comment: Can you add the code for `postFactory` in your question?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: I suppose that the promise returned from the `getPastPosts()` function via `$http` is not being resolved. Can you check your console for errors when the function is called upon scroll?

Comment: There are no errors and the data is completely correct. In a standard http angular format.

Answer (score 0):

You could got an object in getPastPosts() if data returns a value.

The infinite scroll would not be work because it is not an array.

infiniteItems must be type of array.

try like this,

```
if(data.size == 1){ // I don't know your data structure.
   this.push(data.data);
}else{
   this = data.data
}
```